# Dynamic scale dependency from attribute query using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, features, scale, feature-class

If I have a feature class called roads with an attribute for type e.g. highway etc.

Is there a way to setup a dynamic scale dependency on the layer based on the type of road?

Like do a SQL query and apply a specific scale dependency range on the  records that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would use a Definition Query (see tab on the Layer Properties) using the first SQL query (e.g. RoadType = 'Highway') and then apply the scale dependency to that query defined layer.

For another road type make a copy of the above layer and then give it a different definition query (and scale dependency).

Repeat as many times as necessary.

If you want to be able to turn all the above layers on/off as one then select them in the Table of Contents and right-click to choose Group.

Comment: Would multiple layers pointing to the same feature class having issues standing up as a WFS in ArcGIS Server 10.0?

Comment: That is best researched/asked as another question.  I would be surprised if it did but I have no experience in that area to draw on.

Comment: Thought I had an issue with that before, I'll play with this method